# Purescript - iterate a longish array

Tags: purescript

The following code, being executed in Chrome, fails after printing `7492`:

```
module Main where

import Prelude
import Effect (Effect)
import Effect.Console as Console
import Data.Array as Array
import Data.Traversable (for_)

main :: Effect Unit
main = do
  for_ (Array.range 1 10000) Console.logShow
```

What am I doing wrong here? How can I iterate over longer arrays without causing a stack overflow?

The code is compiled using `spago build` and runs using `parcel`.

Fragment of `package.json`:

```json
  "devDependencies": {
    "parcel": "2.7.0",
    "purescript": "^0.15.4",
    "spago": "^0.20.9"
  }
```

UPD: In Orion, execution interrupts after 33793 iterations. Safari reaches 8000, getting slower and slower. This is on the "production" build of the script — `spago bundle-app --to prod/index.js && parcel build prod/index.html`.

Answer (score 1):

The [`Control.Safely`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-safely/4.0.1/docs/Control.Safely#v:for_) module provides a stack-safe `for_`.

```
import Control.Safely (for_)

main :: Effect Unit
main = do
  for_ (Array.range 1 10000) Console.logShow
```

This `for_` can be applied to a monad that is an instance of `MonadRec`, where `Effect` is that instance.

Answer (score 0):

```
Effect.foreachE (Array.range 1 100000) Console.logShow
```

seems to be working.